# UE4.9 C++ Puzzle Block Addressing

Tags: c++, memory-address, unreal-engine4

In UE4 I am working on a Puzzle Block game in my Graphics 2 class. Our professor and our class is learning about UE4 together. Our class as a whole is a little confused about one thing in the C++ code and my professor said he would try to figure the answer out himself, but I figured I would jump start our next class with information that I find here.

Okay so in the BlockGrid.cpp file this section of code is used to create the blocks.

```
void AMyProject2BlockGrid::BeginPlay()
{
   Super::BeginPlay();

   // Number of blocks
   const int32 NumBlocks = Size * Size;

   // Loop to spawn each block
   for(int32 BlockIndex=0; BlockIndex<NumBlocks; BlockIndex++)
   {
      const float XOffset = (BlockIndex/Size) * BlockSpacing; // Divide by dimension
      const float YOffset = (BlockIndex%Size) * BlockSpacing; // Modulo gives remainder

      // Make postion vector, offset from Grid location
      const FVector BlockLocation = FVector(XOffset, YOffset, 0.f) + GetActorLocation();

      // Spawn a block
      AMyProject2Block* NewBlock = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AMyProject2Block>(BlockLocation, FRotator(0,0,0));

      // Tell the block about its owner
      if(NewBlock != NULL)
      {
          NewBlock->OwningGrid = this;
      }
   }
}
```

The confusion starts with the following line in this function:

```
AMyProject2Block* NewBlock = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AMyProject2Block>(BlockLocation, FRotator(0,0,0));
```

Each time it looks like it is rewriting NewBlock for each new block in the puzzle. Our problem is for the game we are creating, which is a [Lights Out game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29), is if NewBlock is being continually being rewritten, then how is it keeping track of the addresses for the information to the blocks that are being displayed on the screen? This could be fixed by simply creating an array to store the information, but if the information is still being kept somewhere this would be inefficient. So how can we access the information for the blocks if NewBlock is being overwritten with each loop without making an array to inefficiently store the data?

THANKS!!!! :)

Comment: Note: I do not know any specifics of UE4. Based on the code above (which I'm guessing is boilerplate from elsewhere), the world (from `GetWorld()`) keeps a reference to the spawned Actor, so the `NewBlock` pointer is there just so the `OwningGrid` field can be set. Any further access to Actors in the world would have to find that reference by another means. (See, for example: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/16805/c-find-specific-actor-in-scene.html).  Note that keeping an array of pointers is not inefficient, though I don't know UE4's policy on keeping Actor pointers.

Answer (score 0):

@Mathew's comment has the right idea, when you use `SpawnActor`, Unreal does a whole bunch of behind the scenes stuff but essentially creates your actor inside the world and manages its lifetime.  (For example, to remove your actor from the level, you would need to use:

```
MyActor->Destroy();
```

Rather than the C++ method:

```
delete PtrToActor;
```

This handles removing it from the scene, updating collision volumes etc. before actually deleting the actor.

To your code, you are of course overwriting the pointer to your block, so the block itself is left untouched. You can use the [`TActorIterator<T>` iterable](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Iterators:_Object_%26_Actor_Iterators,_Optional_Class_Scope_For_Faster_Search#Actor_Iterator) to loop through all actors of a type which would save you having to store an array yourself. You would do something like this:

```
for (TActorIterator<AMyProject2Block> ActorItr(GetWorld()); ActorItr; ++ActorItr )
{
     AMyProject2Block* PtrToActor = *ActorItr;
}
```

Where here the `PtrToActor` will point to each instance in turn as the loop advances.

However, it isn't really inefficient (and in many cases, is efficient) to store your own separate array of pointers. It is only a small memory cost (since it is just pointers) and might be faster as you don't have to filter the actors to find the one you want. In either case, it is a much of a muchness so you should choose whichever one feels more logical.

In your example, I'd keep them in 2D data structure so you can access them via their position rather than just getting an un-ordered list of them from the engine.